# Java X500 principal name canonicalization with T61String AVAs

Tags: java, ssl, x509

I am using X500 principal equality in Java (JDK 8).

Using `openssl s_client ...`  I see that the subject DN of the certificate I am interested in is reported as (only the CN is shown):

```
CN=*.myserver.net,...
```

However in Java:

```
X509Certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().equals("CN=*.myserver.net,...")
```

reports `false` i.e. that the two values are NOT equal. Looking at the implementation of `.equals`, it appears that the canonical forms of the `X500Name`'s are compared for equality, which makes sense.

I see, however, that the canonical name of the certificate from the server is actually in the following form:

```
cn=#somehex,...
```

while the canonical name of the manually created principal is in the following form:

```
cn=*.myserver.net,...
```

which of course results in them being (incorrectly) unequal.

Investigating further, the relevant logic appears to be in `sun.security.x509.AVA.isDerString` which checks for `tag = 12` (`UTF8String`) or `tag = 19` (`PrintableString`), whereas this CN RDN appears to have `tag = 20` (`T61String`).

The [canonicalization docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal.html#getName-java.lang.String-) do not indicate why the CN of the server certificate is being canonicalized to this hex form. According to [RFC 2253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt) section 2.4, the hexadecimal form should be used if the AttributeValue does not have a String representation. However, that is not the case here -- a [T61String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU_T.61) (teletype) certainly has a String representation.

Is the JDK canonicalization of a T61String value into its hex form the correct behaviour?